# IndexOfAll function for string, with count parameter

Tags: .net, vb.net

I would like to write a **IndexOfAll** function that must return the indices of all the occurrences of the given pattern found within that string.

The function has a **startIndex** and **count** parameters like one of the overloads of the built-in .NET function: **string.IndexOf()**

The count parameter, like in the built-in .NET function, it will represent the number / max. range of character positions to examine in the source string.

The problem is that I'm breaking my head trying to figure how to properly calculate the value for **count**. Probably this would be a very easy mathematical calculation but I don't get it, and I end up with negative numeric values for **count** (that's why I have a try/catch block in the code below, because due the wrong count value calculation I end getting a exception)...

So, how I calculate the **count** value?. This is what I have:

```
Public Function IndexOfAll(str As String,
                           find As String,
                           startIndex As Integer,
                           count As Integer,
                           comparisonType As StringComparison) As Integer()

    Dim indices As New Collection(Of Integer)()
    Dim index As Integer = str.IndexOf(find, startIndex, count, comparisonType)
    indices.Add(index)

    Do
        startIndex = index + 1
        count = ???
        ' Console.WriteLine($"idx {index}, start {startIndex}, count {count}")
        Try
            index = str.IndexOf(find, startIndex, count, comparisonType)
            indices.Add(index)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Exit Do
        End Try
    Loop

    Return indices.ToArray()

End Function
```

**NOTE:** calling the built-in `string.IndexOf()` function it's fine for me, at least for now. I don't pretend to try implement complex string parsing algorithms (that maybe could be broken) to do exact the same as `string.IndexOf()` but with just in few less seconds or milliseconds depending on how large the string is.

Comment: `IndexOf` returns `-1` if there is no match, you are not checking for this. You could remove the first `IndexOf` and move `startIndex = index + 1` to the end of the loop

Comment: Remarks section and sample code of [IndexOf(String, Int32, Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-6.0#system-string-indexof(system-string-system-int32-system-int32)) -- You could also return the Indexes of `Regex.Matches()` Where the first Index is outside the bounds of [Start; Start + Count -1]

Comment: @Charlieface I'm aware of it. Thanks for answer. I just didn't added it because I was testing the **count** negative values. The code was incomplete.

Comment: @Jimi thanks for linking the code examples section of that article, which shows a example of exactly the same that I would like to do. The solution in the code that I shared is that easy as I expected: `count = {string length} - startIndex` - I was blocked trying to figure the right factor to subtract from, I'm bad at math in general. That code example from MSDN helped me a lot.

Comment: But I noticed the **count** variable in that example is for searching in the entire string. I have problems when using a specific count that does not take the entire string length (the problem is finally solved with the accepted answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the end index (`startIndex + count`), and then subtract the new start index.

You'll also want to check the index before adding it to the list.

```
Public Function IndexOfAll(
    str As String,
    find As String,
    startIndex As Integer,
    count As Integer,
    comparisonType As StringComparison) As Integer()
    
    Dim endIndex As Integer = startIndex + count
    Dim indices As New Collection(Of Integer)()
    Dim index As Integer = str.IndexOf(find, startIndex, count, comparisonType)
    
    Do While index <> -1
        indices.Add(index)
        startIndex = index + 1
        count = endIndex - startIndex
        index = str.IndexOf(find, startIndex, count, comparisonType)
    Loop
    
    Return indices.ToArray()
End Function
```

Comment: You made it easy, thanks a lot. It works as expected. Sometimes I get blocked figuring what at first sight should be easy math calculations (**endIndex = startIndex + count** and **count = endIndex - startIndex**). Imagine how I suffer for really complex calculations. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with a LINQ one-liner

```vb
Public Function IndexOfAll(source As String, find As String, startIndex As Integer, count As Integer, comparisonType As StringComparison) As IEnumerable(Of Integer)
    Return source.
        Skip(startIndex).
        Take(source.Length - find.Length - startIndex + 1).
        Select(Function(c, i) source.IndexOf(find, i + startIndex, count, comparisonType)).
        Where(Function(i) i >= 0)
End Function
```

The purpose of Skip and Take is to look at only those first characters where we will start comparison. The Select takes the character and its index. But since we Skip, we need to add the startIndex back within IndexOf. Select then returns the character position. Where returns only those character positions which are non negative.